# Using token with different delimiters

Tags: c, string, token, strtok

I am trying to put all integers in an array with delimiters between them

What I would expect to see

```
array[0][0] = 0
array[0][1] = 1
array[1][1] = 2
array[2][1] = 3
array[0][2] = 4
```

I have tried reuse token = strtok( str, ";" ) but it removes char "4"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
char seps[] = " ,\t\n\r";
char *token;
char str[1000] = "0,1;2;3,4";
int kk=0;
int array[3][10];

token = strtok( str, seps );
while(1){
    sscanf(token,"%d",&(array[0][kk]));
    printf("Print Token %d\n",array[0][kk]);
    //If token has ; move to next place in 1st array
    token = strtok( NULL, seps );
    kk++;
    if (token==NULL)
        break;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never look for a semicolon.

Comment: @David It is better to write the loop like while( token != NULL ){ /* ...*/ kk++; token = strtok( NULL, seps ); }

Answer (score 0):

Not all separaters are included in the array `seps`.

Also the while loop should be written like

```
token = strtok( str, seps );
while( token != NULL )
{
    // ...
    ++kk;
    token = strtok( NULL, seps );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    const char seps[] = " ;,\t\n\r";
    char *token;
    char str[1000] = "0,1;2;3,4";
    int array[3][10];

    size_t i = 0;
    token = strtok( str, seps );

    while ( token != NULL )
    {
        sscanf( token, "%d", &array[0][i] );

        printf( "%d ", array[0][i] );

        ++i;

        token = strtok( NULL, seps );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: I am trying to put 1 2 3 @
array[0][1] = 1
array[1][1] = 2
array[2][1] = 3

if there are ";" between them string

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `strtok`, at least not easily, because `strtok` erases any delimiters it finds without any indication of what they were. So problems involving distinguishing between different types of delimiter are not suitable for `strtok`.

I'd suggest you try an approach which attempts to match the fields you want to extract, and then examines the delimiter character which follows the matched field. (You might want to skip whitespace as well, but that's a simple modification.)

If you are looking for numbers, you'll find `strtol` (or `strtod` for floating point) is very useful, because it both extracts the number and tells you where the number ends. You can then examine the character at the indicated endpoint, and restart the scan at the next character after that.